# How do I include my first commit in my cherry pick command?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

**Cliffnotes version**

- Assume I want to run this command: `git cherry-pick ABC..XYZ`. I want `ABC` to be included in my commits to the current branch. Do I have to reference the commit before `ABC`?

**Long Version**

- So I have branches `master`, `Apple` and `NewApple`.
- `Apple` was built upon a very old version of `master` but only worked on a dozen files which were implemented on folders which the rest of the `master` did not really touch.
- `Apple` has commits `ABC`, `BCD`, and `XYZ`. These are commits unique to `Apple`. Please note there are about 10 commits between `BCD` and `XYZ. These commits were NEVER commited to`master`
- So I made a new branch `NewApple` which is spun off of a newer versions of `master`, ones with newer commits.
- Then I cherry-picked commits from `Apple` to put onto `NewApple` like so `git cherry-pick ABC..XYZ`
- However, when finished and committed to my remote repository, I noticed that `ABC` was not included. Everything after it and including `XYZ` were put onto `NewApple`.
- I want to be able to commit `ABC` as part of my cherry-pick without referencing the commit that is before it in `Apple`. I am afraid that if I do, I won't get all the commits in `Apple` or it will try to merge in random older `master` commits on top of newer versions of master.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... `git cherry-pick ABC..XYZ` [but] I want `ABC` to be included in my commits to the current branch. Do I have to reference the commit before `ABC`?

Short answer: yes.

Longer variety of answer: Git has a syntax for that, since it's such a common requirement.  Any name suitable for identifying one specific commit, such as `master` or `a123456`, can be suffixed with `^` or `~` characters followed by numbers.  The default number is just 1, and hence:

```
master^
```

or

```
master~
```

means "the commit before the one selected by the name `master`".

In this case, then, you might write:

```
git cherry-pick ABC^..XYZ
```

Note that Windows-y command line interpreters tend to treat `^` as an escape character, requiring entering the command using `ABC^^..XYZ` or `"ABC^..XYZ"`, so there you might prefer `~`.  Either one works here.

(More specifically, `^number` means the *number*-th parent, while `~number` tells Git to count back that many first-parents.  So `master~3` means the same as `master^1^1^1`.  Since `1` is the default number, you can write this as `master^^^` as well.  There are many more ways to identify commits, all outlined in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I learned a lot!

Comment: @Andry: to me, that seems weird, because I don't use Windows. :-) Also all the programming languages I use most use backslash as the escape (C, C++, Go, Python, etc). But I'll edit.